# How to change default paths for Storybook and Storybook addons?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, storybook

**Summary**

I'm trying to run SB on a Next app running in a restricted Windows environment. I'm not sure what the function of `node_modules/.cache/sb-manager` is, but it's setting absolute Windows paths that can't be accessed in my environment. Like `C:\USERS\USERNAME\DONT COME IN HERE!` (see below)

What can instead be accessed is the git bash root path like `~/Documents/happy_path`. I've got the app to work, and then not, so I'm not sure what it's doing that I'm missing. Do I have to remove all the addons? Error messages below.

We're running Node v20.8.1 with Storybook 7.6.17. React is version 18.2, Next is version 13.1.2.

**Question:** How to change the default path that addons and/or `sb-manager` is using?

**Additional information**

On `npm run storybook`:

The error message is `Cannot read directory ../../../My Documents": Access is denied.` Of course it is, that's the restricted part of the environment.

And then following from that a repeated `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference in...` for every file in `sb-manager`

**What it does:**

Every file in `sb-manager` sets a path to `'c:/Users/XXXXX/Documents/XXXX/node_modules/@storybook/addon-whatever...'`

**What I want it to do:**

It would be nice if that path could somehow instead be set to `'~/Documents/XXXX/node_module/@storybook/addon-whatever...'`

**Error Message**

On `npm run storybook`:

```
> vc-app@0.1.0 storybook
> storybook dev -p 6006
 
@storybook/cli v7.6.17
 
info => Serving static files from ./.\public at /
info => Starting manager..
X [ERROR] Cannot read directory "../../../My Documents": Access is denied.
 
X [ERROR] panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference (while parsing "../../../My Documents/XXX/XXX/node_modules/.cache/sb-manager/essentials-actions-2/manager-bundle.js")
 
  debug.Stack (runtime/debug/stack.go:24)
  helpers.PrettyPrintedStack (internal/helpers/stack.go:9)
  bundler.parseFile.func1 (internal/bundler/bundler.go:189)
  panic (runtime/panic.go:884)
  resolver.resolverQuery.tsConfigForDir (internal/resolver/resolver.go:977)
  resolver.resolverQuery.resolveWithoutSymlinks (internal/resolver/resolver.go:828)
  resolver.(*Resolver).Resolve (internal/resolver/resolver.go:577)
  bundler.RunOnResolvePlugins (internal/bundler/bundler.go:901)
  bundler.parseFile (internal/bundler/bundler.go:397)
  bundler.(*scanner).maybeParseFile (internal/bundler/bundler.go:1385)
 
X [ERROR] panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference (while parsing "../../../My Documents/XXX/XXX/node_modules/.cache/sb-manager/essentials-controls-1/manager-bundle.js")
 
  debug.Stack (runtime/debug/stack.go:24)
  helpers.PrettyPrintedStack (internal/helpers/stack.go:9)
  bundler.parseFile.func1 (internal/bundler/bundler.go:189)
  panic (runtime/panic.go:884)
  resolver.resolverQuery.tsConfigForDir (internal/resolver/resolver.go:977)
  resolver.resolverQuery.resolveWithoutSymlinks (internal/resolver/resolver.go:828)
  resolver.(*Resolver).Resolve (internal/resolver/resolver.go:577)
  bundler.RunOnResolvePlugins (internal/bundler/bundler.go:901)
  bundler.parseFile (internal/bundler/bundler.go:397)
  bundler.(*scanner).maybeParseFile (internal/bundler/bundler.go:1385)
```

**Storybook Config**

`.storybook/main.js`

```
/** @type { import('@storybook/nextjs').StorybookConfig } */
const config = {
    stories: [
        "../stories/**/*.mdx",
        ../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx),
        ../components/**/*.stories.@(js|ts),
    ],
    addons: [
        "@storybook/addon-links",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials",
        "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions",
        "@storybook/addon-designs",
    ],
    framework: {
        name: "@storybook/nextjs",
        options: {},
    },
    core: {
        disableTelemetry: true,
    },
    docs: {
        autodocs: "tag",
    },
}
export default config
```

Comment: Can you provide your configuration for storybook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found out so far is that the [`builder-manager`](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/code/builders/builder-manager/src/utils/managerEntries.ts#L41) wraps the manager entries like this:

```
export async function wrapManagerEntries(entrypoints: string[], uniqueId?: string) {
  return Promise.all(
    entrypoints.map(async (entry, i) => {
      const { name, dir } = parse(entry);
      const cacheLocation = resolvePathInStorybookCache('sb-manager', uniqueId);

      if (!cacheLocation) {
        throw new Error('Could not create/find cache directory');
      }

      const base = relative(process.cwd(), dir);
      const location = join(
        cacheLocation,
        sanitizeFinal(join(`${sanitizeBase(base)}-${i}`, `${sanitizeBase(name)}-bundle.js`))
      );

      await fs.ensureFile(location);
      await fs.writeFile(location, `import '${slash(entry)}';`);

      return location;
    })
  );
}
```

I think the problem lies in the [`resolvePathInStorybookCache`](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/c9d7eb1995b627bd7e4ef522b863a230a25f02e4/code/lib/core-common/src/utils/resolve-path-in-sb-cache.ts#L12) function which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Get the path of the file or directory with input name inside the Storybook cache directory:
 *  - `node_modules/.cache/storybook/{directoryName}` in a Node.js project or npm package
 *  - `.cache/storybook/{directoryName}` otherwise
 *
 * @param fileOrDirectoryName {string} Name of the file or directory
 * @return {string} Absolute path to the file or directory
 */
export function resolvePathInStorybookCache(fileOrDirectoryName: string, sub = 'default'): string {
  let cacheDirectory = findCacheDirectory({ name: 'storybook' });
  cacheDirectory ||= path.join(process.cwd(), '.cache', 'storybook');

  return path.join(cacheDirectory, sub, fileOrDirectoryName);
}
```

Now my guess is that the poroblem lies in [`findCacheDirectory`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/find-cache-dir) which resolves to absolute urls, but if we check the source code we can see that it uses `CACHE_DIR` environment variable that lets you specify the location.

So the solution would be to try to set something like `CACHE_DIR=~/Documents/XXXX/node_modules/.cache` (the correct path to the project).

Comment: Interesting...let me try that.

Comment: That was exactly it!  Kicking myself for not checking the source code.  Thanks @vl4d1m1r4!